# Powershell Export SharePont Taxonomy

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, taxonomy

I am trying to export the taxonomy from a SharePoint online site and having trouble getting the TermSet and Terms to printout in the csv file.  I get the Group headings to print but then only blank lines for the TermSet and Terms part of the list.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for the help.

It does connect to the SharePoint site.  Here is the code:

```
#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site - required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString

#Bind to MMS
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds
$MMS = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($Context)
$Context.Load($MMS)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Retrieve Term Stores
$TermStores = $MMS.TermStores
$Context.Load($TermStores)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Bind to Term Store
$TermStore = $TermStores[0]
$Context.Load($TermStore)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Retrieve Groups
$Groups = $TermStore.Groups
$Context.Load($Groups)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Retrieve TermSets in each group
$csvFileName = "c:\CTSTermSet.csv"
$results = @()
$groupName = @()
$termSetName = @()
$termName = @()

Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
    {
    $Context.Load($Group)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "Group Name:" $Group.Name -ForegroundColor Green
     $details = @{
                       GroupName       = $Group.Name
          }
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details

    $TermSets = $Group.TermSets
    $Context.Load($TermSets)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    Foreach ($TermSet in $TermSets)
        {
        $Context.Load($TermSets)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Host "Term Set Name:"$TermSet.Name -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host "Terms:" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
         $details = @{
                     TermSetName       = $TermSet.Name
            }
         $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
         $Terms = $TermSet.Terms
         $Context.Load($Terms)
         $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        Foreach ($Term in $Terms)
            {
             Write-Host "" $Term.Name -ForegroundColor White
             $details = @{
                     Term                    = $Term.Name
                }
             $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
           } #End Foreach ($Term in $Terms)
         }  #End Foreach ($TermSet in $TermSets)
    }    #End Foreach ($Grouup in$Group)
    $results | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $csvFileName
```

Comment: if I were you I'd look at some of the modules on powershellgallery.com like this one:  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline/2.28.1807.0 it has taxonomy modules in it.

Answer (score 0):

The following PowerShell for your reference.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"

#Variables for Processing
$AdminURL = "https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$ReportOutput="C:\Temp\TermStoreData.csv"

Try {
    #Get Credentials to connect
    $Cred = Get-Credential
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($AdminURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

     #Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
    $ResultCollection = @()

    #Get the term store
    $TaxonomySession=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($Ctx)
    $TermStore =$TaxonomySession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore()
    $Ctx.Load($TaxonomySession)
    $Ctx.Load($TermStore)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Get all term groups  
    $TermGroups = $TermStore.Groups
    $Ctx.Load($TermGroups)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Iterate through each term group
    Foreach($Group in $TermGroups)
    {
        #Get all Term sets in the Term group
        $TermSets = $Group.TermSets
        $Ctx.Load($TermSets)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Iterate through each termset
        Foreach($TermSet in $TermSets)
        {
            #Get all Terms from the term set
            $Terms = $TermSet.Terms
            $Ctx.Load($Terms)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            #Iterate through each term
            Foreach($Term in $Terms)
            {
                $TermData = new-object PSObject
                $TermData | Add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group" -Value $Group.Name
                $TermData | Add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "TermSet" -Value $Termset.Name
                $TermData | Add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Term" -Value $Term.Name  
                $ResultCollection += $TermData
            }
        }
    }
    #Export Results to a CSV File
    $ResultCollection | Export-csv $ReportOutput -notypeinformation

    Write-host "Term Store Data Successfully Exported!" -ForegroundColor Green  
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Exporting Termstore Data!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

References:

[SharePoint Online: Export Term Store Data to CSV using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-export-term-store-data.html)

[SharePoint Online / Office 365 - Exporting All the Terms from Particular TermSet In .CSV File Using CSOM And Console Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-online-office-365-exporting-all-the-terms-from-particular-termset/)

Comment: How would you go about getting more than 2 levels deep?  Exporting all of the data out of the Term Store?